# Manter ordenacao org.json JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Estou enfrentando um problema no java tem alguns dias e nao encontro uma solucao que me ajude a resolver.

Eu tenho uma funcao que executa uma procedure no banco de dados e me retorna um JSON. Eu preciso converter este retorno em um JSONObject para poder acessar os arrays e consequentemente descarregar os dados em xls e csv.

Porem, quando eu faco a conversao para JSONObject ele perde a ordenacao na qual o banco me retornou.

Segue meu código :

```
public Report buildCsv(@NonNull Report.Type type,
                       @NonNull String ev_json_in,
                       @NonNull String titulo) throws IOException {;
    StringBuffer dados = repository.getJson(ev_json_in);
    var data = dados.toString();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
```

A variavel "**data**" esta com a ordenacao correta, porem a "**json**" fica com outra ordenacao.

Vi alguns posts dizendo para mudar a classe JSONObject de HashMap para LinkedHashMap que iria resolver. E de fato resolve, mas quando tratamos de montar o json via put e nao passando um StringBuffer no meu caso.

Na imagem a seguir posso ilustrar melhor o problema;

[variavel data e json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDhAr.png)

Comment: Um *JSON object*, por definição, é um conjunto de pares chave-valor sem ordem definida (*unordered*). Claro que algumas libs preservam a ordem, mas isso é detalhe de implementação. Se quer mesmo manter a ordem, pode usar as soluções [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9909066) (inclusive, uma delas cita o `LinkedHashMap`, e outras sugerem libs diferentes). Mas como a especificação diz que a ordem não importa, melhor seguir [este conselho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515863) e rever a aplicação para que ela não dependa da ordem (e se não tiver jeito mesmo, use alguma das soluções indicadas)

Comment: @hkotsubo eu tentei realizar o seguinte ajuste.
   `
try {
            Field changeMap = jsonObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("map");
            changeMap.setAccessible(true);
            changeMap.set(jsonObject, new LinkedHashMap<>());
            changeMap.setAccessible(false);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`

porem quando eu passo um CLOB para montar o JSONObject ele nao resolve.

Esta solucao so atende quando passo os valores como .put

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solucao para este caso foi migrar para o uso do GSON, ele preserva a ordenacao nativa do json para o array.

Segue codigo de exemplo;

```
var header = array.get(0).getAsJsonObject().keySet();
    for (int j = 0; j < header.size(); j++) {
        for (Object cab : header) {
            rowhead.createCell(j).setCellValue(cab.toString());
            j++;
        }
    }

    int l = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {

        for (Object aray : array){
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) l);
            JsonObject values = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            Set<String> keys = values.keySet();
            int c = 0;
            for (String key: keys) {
                row.createCell(c).setCellValue(values.get(key).toString());
                c++;
            }
        }
        l++;
    }
```